# Removal of phrase that gives tone to an answer

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

[This edit](https://law.stackexchange.com/revisions/81523/4) (Revision 4, to be clear) removed the phrase " Welcome to the reality." from [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/81523/17500). If I am not mistaken, I had previously rejected this or a very similar edit to that answer. In my view that phrase indicates that the assumptions behind the question are, in the opinion of the user posting the answer, naive. As such i think it is a significant part o the author's intent, and should remain. I almost rolled back that edit, but did not want to edit-war.

Should this edit be undone? Should similar edits be acceptable in the future?

Answer (score 3):

> Should this edit be undone?

Yes, it should be rolled back. The audience ought to reflect their feedback by voting or preferably in the form of comments, not by single-handedly mutilating a contributor's post. That edit in particular does not improve the post whatsoever.

The reason for edit reads "*Remove clause that is irrelevant to the answer*", which is nit-picky. Stack Exchange does not require that each and every word in a post be strictly relevant to the topic. A requirement so extreme would be absurdly stringent and disconnected from the fact that contributors are humans with an idiosyncrasy in an informal setting, not robots. The phrase "*Welcome to the reality*" is brief and really does not deviate from the topic.

The "*patronizing connotation*" the editing user imputes to this short phrase reflects some reader's hypersensitivity. That does not warrant censoring the answer.

> Should similar edits be acceptable in the future?

No. These edits are a mix of micro-management, an unrealistic demand for political correctness, and sometimes laziness.

Answer (score 2):

### For mine, leave it alone

That sentence doesn’t add much either way to the main thrust of the answer. In addition, I t could, in an uncharitable light, be considered a dig at the question.

If the OP wants to roll it back, that would be fine but I don’t think it’s an egregious enough edit for third-parties to get involved.

Answer (score -3):

> Should similar edits be acceptable in the future?

Strictly speaking, a post edited by someone other than the author is no longer the author's post. This is often tolerable for questions (where the OPs are newbies), but for answers I would advocate for a total ban of edits not approved by their authors.

Either an answer stands as the author pleases, or it needs to be deleted. No grey areas, no ambiguities, no judgment calls/debates as to the author's intent, degree of similarity of the edits to those in established precedents and so on.

Comment: -1 I must disagrwe with this. One does not need permission to correct typos. An answer that mixes good content with spam should be edited to have the spam removed. There are other possible cases.

Comment: I agree with David except as to spam.  [Do not edit spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110031/165261).