# Where can I read the Law Stack Exchange policy forbidding images of text?

Tags: discussion, policy

I recently posted an answer that included an image of text. This answer was repeatedly edited to remove that image, which I repeatedly restored to the answer. Dale M tells me that the Law Stack Exchange has a policy of not allowing pictures of text.

Where are these policies promulgated? I don't see any help on this point at the Help Center.

And is there a "meta" exchange such as many other stack exchanges have, to keep a question like this one (about the policies of the exchange itself) out of the way of the substantive discussions?

**PART 2: WHERE THINGS STAND**

Rick was one of the original participants in deleting my image, and now he has sent me a link to the Meta site. I still have not found any indication of the supposed policy against images of text. There is a question at the Meta site (also flagged by Rick) about whether we should have such a policy. That question (like this question) also mentions the efforts of Dale M, and the question seems to suggest that we do not actually have this policy.

It seems to me that to the contrary, there are one or two zealous members of the exchange imposing this personal enthusiasm on the exchange by down-voting, editing or deleting disobedient contributions.

Should it work that way?

**PART 3**

Dale M, seeming lone champion of this supposed rule, has answered as follows: *It is not a Law Stack Exchange policy; it is a [Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) policy. It will be enforced here and, I trust, on all other sites.*

But that link in the words "Stack Exchange" goes not to a statement of the rules by the Stack Exchange, but to a conversation on another stack exchange, Stack Overflow. I'm not clear how that is an answer to my question.

Taryn's answer there does not say (as Dale says) that the Stack Exchange forbids images of text; rather it says that under some circumstances a user uploading an image will receive an automatic message that says, "Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. " I did not receive that message, perhaps because the policy is not in fact a Stack Exchange policy but the policy of that other exchange. My post was still clear and useful without the image, so, as far as I can tell the objection still may be merely Dale's preference.

So as a procedural matter, is there any way for a user to know the policies of the Stack Exchange directly, not in remarks written to him in particular but in some published statement of the rules?

Or, failing that, what should happen if someone repeatedly removes an image from my post for reasons that cannot really be explained?

**PART 4**

It's been 8 hours since Dale M last asserted the rule here, and nobody seems to know about this rule except for him. I guess that if 24 hours pass with no evidence of the rule except for Dale's assertions, I'm going to "roll back" those edits to re-include the image and see what happens next. Perhaps the question will then become whether the Stack Exchange offers any remedy where a user assumes emergency powers.

Comment: This is specifically addressed on [Law.SE here](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/should-we-have-an-explicit-policy-against-images-of-text).

Comment: @feetwet I'm having that weird Stack Exchange disconnect. That's the same discussion that I mentioned in my letter, to which Rick directed me. I realize that people (on this exchange and others) sometimes ask the policy on positing images or assert that policy is so-and-so. I could make such assertions too, if I were not so shy. Is there no way to rise above that conversation to some authoritative statement of policy?

Comment: Wow, I feel your frustration Chaim.  No source document.  Links to discussions about policy, but nothing to the policy itself.  Just circular and obtuse references.  This is exactly how rumors propagate.  I would expect more from those in charge of enforcement.  (Especially on a LAW site!) Let’s see if they can do better…

Comment: @Chaim - I have updated the link in my answer to point to the Stack Exchange Meta.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155600/allowed-to-post-scanned-page-from-text-book-on-se/155601#155601 for an SE network-wide statement

Answer (score 7):

While it's true there is no explicit policy against it - there's been clear statements from staff on the network (not just Stack Overflow) strongly advising users not to do this.

> Dale M, seeming lone champion of this supposed rule,

Not at all, if it were not clear from the various users' posts on the MSE post Dale links to, you can read my support (or championing if you will) of such a policy [here](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/should-we-have-an-explicit-policy-against-images-of-text/1489#1489) and read the quotes/follow the links in my post  to read what Stack Exchange staff have to say on the issue. But if you would rather I state it here fine - this notion/policy/guideline/rule whatever term you prefer is something I **wholeheartedly** support.

> It's been 8 hours since Dale M last asserted the rule here, and nobody seems to know about this rule except for him.

Remember that SE is a highly asynchronous platform covering literally the whole range of time zones - sometimes it can take a while for people to see things.

> I guess that if 24 hours pass with no evidence of the rule except for Dale's assertions, I'm going to "roll back" those edits to re-include the image and see what happens next.

I don't see what you hope to achieve by doing so, if your complaint is that SE doesn't have an explicit enough policy on the matter you can contact them [directly](https://law.stackexchange.com/contact) or you can ask on [Main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: Can you explain to me (1) what it means for someone to be "staff," (2) what it means for someone (like Dale) to have that [*Mod] symbol following his name, and what it means for users to be "strongly advised" of something -- that is, is it advice in the normal sense, where (in a conversation between equals) each of us free to attach whatever weight we like to the advice we receive?

Comment: @Chaim Staff: exactly what it says on the tin - Stack Exchange employees, i.e. people who work for [the company](https://stackoverflow.co/), notably the [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-is-on-the-community-management-team-and-what-does-it-do). "Strongly advised": They said "don't do this", and that's not a "conversation between equals" because, well, they're *staff*, they are speaking in their official capacity as a representative of the company that owns and operates the sites.

Comment: @Chaim as for the "Mod" symbol next to Dale's name - SE sites elect their own [volunteer moderators](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) from the community, and Dale is one such for LawSE

Comment: So, when staff strongly advise me to do something, they are in fact imposing that rule on me and I cannot act as I like? And your distinction that "there's no explicit policy against it" is a non-distinction, and this rule against images of text is compulsory?

Comment: @Chaim If you wish to have more guidance/clarification on how you should interpret what the staff have said I'd suggest [asking them directly](https://law.stackexchange.com/contact)

Comment: The truth is, I still don't think that this worked out correctly. It seems to me that there's no legitimate objection to my including the image that I wanted to include, and I felt that Dale was trying to sidestep the process of convincing me by a Roe-vs-Wade-style make-believe procedural argument. And this is story of America today -- trying to keep people from voting, and treating all disagreement as illegitimate, and pulling various procedural stunts to avoid fair participation.

Comment: I followed your link for asking them directly, with no response as far as I know. David Siegal posted a link to a 2012 conversation in which animuson said "we still don't want you to" post an image of text, and after his name appear both "staff" and "*Mod." Yet all of these links to discussions of the merits of the ban don't reach the issue for me. I understand the merits of the ban, but there's still no objection to my image. And (as with many such questions in America) Dale seemed to think that the greater moral virtue on his side justified the pretense of a simple mechanical rule.

Answer (score 5):

### It is not a *Law* Stack Exchange policy; it is a [Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged) guideline

It will be enforced here and, I trust, on all other sites. This is in accordance with the guidance in the [Moderator Agreement Policies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/mod-agreement-policies):

> The vast majority of rules and policies on the network are community-defined and company supported. Those policies often vary by site and may not apply to some sites at all. Additionally, many of the policies you find are "best practices" determined through years of experience as a Q&A platform.

Comment: your link does not support your answer

Comment: The link is Stackoverflow, not Stackexchange. I see meta.stackexchange.com has some related discussions, but of course it's not as important as in programming. In programming it's very important to have text as text, not a screenshot. Maybe I'll have to type out the code in the screenshot (and then make a one character mistake, which will cause issues), or maybe the problem has to do with invisible issues like TABs vs. spaces which don't show up in screenshots at all.  In other domains, maybe it's just slightly annoying or an accessibility problem (e.g. screenreaders) to have text in images.

Comment: @Brandin apologies - link updated

Comment: Do you agree with everything in the answer from @motosubatsu ?

Comment: don't see it in that link either, it's just how you should act as a mod.

Comment: @Chaim more or less

Comment: @TigerGuy did you revisit the revised first link?