# Legally, how does "prevail" differ from "will not be affected"?

Tags: discussion

How can [Legally, how does "prevail" differ from "will not be affected"?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/82462) be salvaged, or rewritten to be on topic? I am uncertain if a moderator unilaterally closed it?

I fancy posting answer that scolds the Landlord, NOT other users.

David Siegel is a nice guy, and has contributed so much to this website. But David Siegel's answer is too balmy. Whether it gets reopened or not, I must point out the Landlord's deliberate ambiguity. David Siegel construed Landlord to mean that the Landlord will not affect tenant protection legislation.

But Tenant must be wary of a deleterious interpretation that can mar the Tenant. The Landlord can construe their "will not be affected" to mean that tenant protection legislation does not affect Tenant — in the sense that tenant protection legislation does not apply to, or, assist Tenant! In this deleterious construal, Landlord is hoodwinking the Tenant to abandon and waive Tenants' rights to tenant protection legislation. Therefore Tenant probably should argue for "prevail", and refuse to sign to "will not be affected".

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> How can Legally, how does "prevail" differ from "will not be affected"? be salvaged, or rewritten to be on topic?

That post was improperly closed. The question is on topic because it pertains to *legal terms and language*, which listed as permissible on [What topics can I ask about here?](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Accordingly, also I voted to reopen it.

Some users take issue with posts worded in first person because to them it sounds like a request for legal advice. The OP's first "horrendous" mistake was the unnecessary clarification that he is the tenant. Editing to third person typically solves their concern. Writing in third person reflects an OP's understanding that no attorney-client implications are to ensue from his inquiry and the answers thereto. Other than that manifestation, I consider the dynamics & expectations about drafting in third-person sort of ritualistic or "superstitious".

Also the paragraph about tenant's inquiries to the counterparty is detrimental to that post. It reinforces some users' *pretext* that the OP are trying to do here something (i.e., a request for legal advice) that got repeatedly rejected elsewhere.

A minor detail is the OP's mention of *speculate*. Obviously the OP is interested in the knowing legal reasoning behind landlord's language, but the term *speculate* will prompt some users to mischaracterize the post as "opinion-based".

> I am uncertain if a moderator unilaterally closed it?

Yes. It was closed unilaterally by a moderator, like SE has no functionality for the community to decide and vote on a post. That is a [recurrent problem](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1477/18505) at least on Law SE.

Comment: @user "*this is not my post.*" Thanks for pointing that out. I should have paid more attention  to that detail. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

### No, it can't be salvaged

Interpretation of detailed specifics of contracts is bang in the middle of "legal advice" which is off-limits here. The choice of language to use and to accept is exactly what lawyers do.

Similarly, a party to a contract shouldn't advise the other party what the contract "means" beyond "it means what it says" lest they damage their position in future legal procedures.

Your valid criticism of DS's answer is one of the reasons *why* it can't be salvaged. The main reason, of course, is that it's against the law to give legal advice unless you are licensed to practice law in the relevant jurisdiction.

Also, don't "scold" other users. Disagree, critique, even lecture, but don't scold.

Comment: I wanted to scold the Landlord. **Not David Siegel or users.** David has contributed so much to this website.

Answer (score 1):

Advising the tenant what language to accept and what o reject is probably over the line into giving legal advice.  Also, it is not our place to "scold" askers here, I think.  It is our place to explain, as best we can, what the law requires or permits in a given situation. When a person asks about specific language in a contract, we can and should try to explain its effect, or probable effect. While I do not think the interpretation above is plausible, you are free to present that view, if you think it correct or likely. If the question is reopened, that is.

I think it is on-topic as it stans, although just barely, I have already voted to reopen it.

Comment: I wanted to scold the Landlord. **Not David Siegel or users.** David has contributed so much to this website. Great to have you here!